# Can't figure out what is wrong (python)

Tags: python

I'm new to programing and have only started intro to programming a few weeks ago. The problem I am having with this program is that after I input the number of pints, after the 7th time, it just gives me a blank line with no error but it also doesn't move on to the rest of the program.

I was wondering what needs to be done, or what it means when that happens?

```
#This program will assist in calculating average pints of blood collected daily for a red cross blood drive
#It will also display the highest value, and lowest value

def main():
    endProgram = 'no'
    print
    while endProgram == 'no':
        print
        totalPints = 0
        averagePints = 0
        highPints = 0
        lowPints = 0
        pints = [0] * 7
        pints = getPints(pints)
        totalPints = getTotal(pints, totalPints)
        averagePints = getAverage(totalPints, averagePints)
        highPints = getHigh(pints, highPints)
        lowPints = getLow(pints, lowPints)
        displayInfo(averagePints, highPints, lowPints)
        endProgram = raw_input('Do you want to end program? (Enter yes or no): ')

        while not (endProgram == 'yes' or endProgram == 'no'):
            print 'Please enter a yes or no'
            endProgram = raw_input('Do you want to end program? (Enter yes or no): ')


def getPints(pints):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        pints[counter] = input('Enter pints collected: ')
        counter = counter + 1
    return pints

def getTotal(pints, totalPints):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        totalPints = totalPints + pints[counter]
        counter = counter + 1
    return totalPints

def getAverage(totalPints, averagePints):
    averagePints = totalPints / 7
    return averagePints

def getHigh(pints,highPints):
    highPints = pints[0]
    counter = 1
    while counter < 7:
        if pints[counter] > highPints:
            highPints = pints[counter]
        counter = counter + 1
        return highPints

def getLow(pints, lowPints):
    lowPints = pints[0]
    counter = 1
    while counter < 7:
        if pints[counter] < lowPints:
            lowPints = pints[counter]
        counter = counter + 1
    return lowPints

def displayInfo(averagePints, highPints, lowPints):
    print 'The average pints of donated blood is: ', averagePints
    print 'The highest pints of blood donated is: ', highPints
    print 'The lowest pints of blood donated is: ', lowPints


main()
```

Comment: Consider incorporating some white space into your code. It will make it easier to read.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error. I get all the info printed correctly. Can you tell us what input you provide?

Comment: Probably unrelated to your immediate problem, but the indentation in `getHigh` looks wrong.

Comment: Adding empty lines between *every* line of code is detrimental to readability. Try to group related statements, with an empty line between more loosely related groups.

Comment: Asking us to debug your entire program is unlikely to get you answers. Show us what you have already tried; try to reduce the problem to an [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - though chances are you will solve the problem yourself in the process.

Comment: Ok the values that I am plugging in are 43, 25, 64, 35, 19, 37, 46. The things I've tried are altering the while loops because I though the program was just stuck in a loop, but it is not the case. I do not know the terminology very well but what happens is after I plug in all of the values it just prints a blank line and the program just stops and doesn't do anything, no error codes, it just stays on that blank line and I just have to kill the program.

Comment: Ok, the problem ended up being the indentation on 'getLow' the line 'counter = counter + 1' needed to be indented to the same level as the if statement. I also made the while loops into while not loops, and switched the < to >=, I don't know if that made a difference but it works now. Thanks for all the suggestions and tips everyone.